# Do Silicon Valley workers send their children to no-phone no-tablet schools?

Tags: psychology, technology

I have heard someone say that there is a considerable proportion of employees of Silicon tech giants that send their children to schools where no smartphones and no tablets are allowed. Allegedly this is because these employees are all too well aware that smartphones and tablets are very addictive, and that they don't want their children to be exposed to the continuous "like" culture.
Is there any evidence that this rumour is true?

Examples.

> You'd think executives at Silicon Valley's top tech firms would be keen to enroll their children in schools chock-full of the latest education technology: one-to-one laptops, iPad programs, digital textbooks, and teachers engaging students using Twitter. But according to The New York Times, some Silicon Valley parents—including the chief technology officer of eBay and execs from Google and Apple—are doing a 180 and sending their kids to the area's decidedly low-tech Waldorf school.

[source](https://www.good.is/articles/why-are-silicon-valley-executives-sending-their-kids-to-a-tech-free-school)

> **Tablets out, imagination in: the schools that shun technology**
>   Parents working in Silicon Valley are sending their children to a school where there’s not a computer in sight – and they’re not alone

[source](https://www.theguardian.com/teacher-network/2015/dec/02/schools-that-ban-tablets-traditional-education-silicon-valley-london)

The [New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2011/10/23/technology/at-waldorf-school-in-silicon-valley-technology-can-wait.html) may require a paid subscription.

Comment: An interesting question. I would like to know the answer. But unfortunately "I have heard someone say" is no good as a proof of notability, which is what questions here need.  So I added some.

Comment: That “someone” is someone I trust. She read it somewhere - so didn’t hear it from someone else - but unfortunately does not remember where. So hence the question whether there could be any truth in it.

Comment: Welcome to the skeptics side of SE, @Oбжорoв! Like @GEdgar said above, this site generally likes claims with sources to them, as well as quantifiable claims (e.g. "x% of employees..." or "more than half of employees..."). Similarly there's a lot of ambiguity around defining "Silicon tech giants". I think this is an interesting question though, and one that could work well on this if it were fleshed out a bit more.  I recommend checking out [the Skeptics.se tour](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour) for some more examples and guidelines of the sort of questions & answers this site aims for.

Comment: The Waldorf School (the one in the NYT article) is a very expensive private school.  The article says "top executives" of Silicon Valley tech firms send their kids there: but I imagine most employees at Apple or Google cannot even remotely afford it.

Comment: I'm still not convinced this is a good question here. Some do maybe, but then so what? What proportion would be required for this to be "true"?

Comment: It is also mentioned in Jaron Lanier's book "Ten Arguments For Deleting Your Social Media Accounts Right Now", p 12.